# How to change text and background color in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, themes

I’m trying to change the text and background color on my WordPress site. I’ve attempted to use the Customize option in the WordPress dashboard, but I can’t seem to find the right settings. I’m using the Astra theme and Elementor page builder. Is there a way to change the text and background color using these tools or do I need to use custom CSS? If so, how can I do this?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You could also toggle a class on the body using `document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode")` and then properly styling your elements accordingly. Eg. in your CSS: body.dark-mode { background-color: #121212; } .dark-mode p { color: #e6e6e6; }

Comment: I edited my question, because i can't add tags - i'm using elementor with wordpress. Its a CMS with a page builder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using **[`*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)** for global style changes other than the standard ones. However, if you **really** want to use this script. This takes precedence over inline styles and CSS styles containing the `!important` rule.

```js
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
  all[i].setAttribute('style', 'background-color: green !important; color: red !important;');
}
```

```css
/* to demonstrate */

body {
  background: white !important;
}

div {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="color: blue;">i'm red? maybe?</div>
```